# Flutter: How to use StreamBuilder with ListView.separated

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, stream, stream-builder

I want a ListView with items from a Stream.
Of course, content of the List should reflect changes in the Stream.
And due to my designer quirks, I want items in the List be separated by a divider.

Just wondering, what is the proper way to create a ListView with separators, and reacting on Stream changes.

```
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: someStream,
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          return ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(color: Colors.black),
            itemCount: ***whatsHere***?,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
...
```

Hope I've missed something.
Since an idea to get somehow the length of the source stream looks at least strange, because of the asynchronous nature of the streams.
It seems might be feasible by StatefullWidget with stream subsriptions (and setState invoking), 
but StreamBuilder is invented to do exactly the same, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`snapshot` can have different states.

Generally you can do something like this:

```
if (snapshot.hasError){
    //return error message
}

if (!snapshot.hasData){
    //return a loader
}

//else you have data
List<your items> = snapshot.data;
// do your thing with ListView.builder
```

For more control you can check the `snapshot.connectionsState` which can be `none`,`done`,`active`,`waiting`.

You can find more [here for the AsyncSnapshot class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) and [here for a quick tutorial](https://medium.com/@sidky/using-streambuilder-in-flutter-dcc2d89c2eae)

Comment: ok, now I see, the main problem was I was intended to use Stream<Data> instead of Stream<List<Data>>. So, since shanpshot couldn't provide me proper information, I sucessfullly ignored it.

Comment: (!snapshot.hasError) - this will return when there is no error.

Comment: uopo, you're right, there's a "!" that shouldn't be there. Fixed, thank you!

Comment: Yes, the insight here is to use `Stream<List<Data>>` instead of `Stream<Data>` and not just checking `!snapshot.hasData`.

Comment: @papirosnik hey, I'm new to flutter, so please bare with my newbie question ;-) how to convert `Stream<Data>` to `Stream<List<Data>>`? my stream comes from websocket (`WebSocketChannel.connect(uri).stream`) and I want to have a `ListView` with a log of received messages. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your `snapshot` should be a list of elements so you can access the `length` of the list like this:

```dart
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: someStream,
        initialData: [],
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          return ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(color: Colors.black),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
                final element = snapshot.data[index];
```

I would suggest to add also the `initialData` to the StreamBuilder so you don't work with a null value in your snapshot.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to know about how can I handle with null value issue if I want to show a simple loading widget while data is being loaded. In that case, initialData will not work.

Answer (score 2):

try this hope it works for you

```
    body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: someStream,
            builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
              return ListView.separated(
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(color: Colors.black),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.lenght,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
    final titre= snapshot.data[index].title ;  // for example

return ListTile ( title : Text(titre)) ;  
     //....
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers say, you can make your stream return **the** list, but that's what Future is for.

If you want your stream to incrementally yield values, you can declare the list inside the class, and add the values for each snapshot received right before the return statement.

You can still receive lists and append them to the bigger list which you would base your builder on.